# How to COPY to Redshift a table where one of the columns is SUPER?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I have a table in csv file where one column `id` is integer and the other `settings` has json in it.

[image]

I tried

```
query_str = f"""
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name};

CREATE TABLE {table_name} (
    "id" integer,
    "settings" super
    );
    
COPY {table_name} ("id", "settings")
    FROM 's3://{bucket}/{key}'
    iam_role '{iam_role}'
    ignoreheader 1
    CSV;
"""
```

i tried replacing `CSV` with something like `FORMAT JSON 'auto'` or `format json 'noshred'` as per [this article](https://blaqfireroundup.wordpress.com/2021/05/14/working-with-the-super-type-in-amazon-redshift/)
. But i think that only applies if your whole table is json.

I'm just getting a generic error `'Error': "ERROR: Load into table 'account_settings' failed.` But it actually doesn't even create the table. When I go look for it in our RS db it's not there.

some entries from the file:

```
1, b'{"address":null,"address2":null,"city":null,"country":null,"customerPortal":null,"features":[{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"achInvoices","name":"ACH Invoices"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"ambassador-autoenroll","name":"Ambassador Auto-Enrollment"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["vanityNumber"],"id":"bibs","name":"Bib Management"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"ccb","name":"CCB"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customReports","name":"Custom Reports"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"customWizard","name":"Custom Wizard For Crossfit (do not enable)"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"emailAutomations","name":"Email Automations"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"extendedDisabledFields","name":"Extended Fields that can be disabled"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"f1","name":"Fellowship 1"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"virtualRace","name":"Virtual Race"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["instagram"],"id":"instagram","name":"Instagram Widget"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"kindful","name":"Kindful Integration"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"massCancellation","name":"Mass Cancellation"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"membership-biyearly","name":"Membership Extra Schedules"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["trackside"],"id":"motocross","name":"Motocross"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"mobilePayPass","name":"Mobile Pay Pass"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"inventoryMultiDay","name":"Multi-Day Sub Inventory (Does not work w/ Timeslots)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"myPassTracker","name":"MyPassTracker"},{"enabled":true,"fields":["password"],"id":"passwordField","name":"Password Field (Not ready at all)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"fieldPassword","name":"Password protected fields"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"saml","name":"SAML Form Authentication"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"webhook-sms","name":"SMS Webhook"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["virtuous"],"id":"virtuous","name":"Virtuous Integration (Do not enable)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"cybersourcerest","name":"Cybersource REST"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"webhook-backend","name":"Webhooks: (Backend: Edit / Cancel)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"billingCountryLockdown","name":"Billing Country Lockdown"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"square","name":"Square Gateway"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"klarna","name":"Klarna Gateway (Crossfit Only)"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"pageTemplates","name":"Page Templates"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customDomains","name":"Custom Domains"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"stripeconnect","name":"Stripe Connect Gateway"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"zebra","name":"Zebra Printer"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"legacyEmailCenter","name":"Legacy Email Center"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"tsystransit","name":"TSYS Transit Pass Gateway"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"contactInsights","name":"Contact Insights"}],"metatags":{"giving.com":[],"red.com":[],"reg.com":[],"ticket.com":[]},"state":null,"timeZone":"America/Denver","zip":null}'
2, b'{"customerPortal":{"contact":{"email":"br45tmn@gmail.com","phone":"6777012345"},"design":{"accentColor":"#38485A","fontColor":"#ffffff","logo":{"image":{"file":"genesis-logo[1].png","fullPath":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.webconnex.com/2/genesis-logo[1].png?150"}}},"welcomeEmail":{"buttonText":"Access your account","fromName":"Minnesota","message":"Hi there,\\n\\nThis is a friendly notice to let you know your account is confirmed and setup.  Visit and bookmark the link below to easily access your account in the future.\\n\\nYou\'re awesome!\\nMinnesota"}},"features":[{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"pageTemplates","name":"Page Templates"},{"enabled":true,"fields":["memberManager"],"id":"memberManager","name":"Member Manager"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["virtuous"],"id":"virtuous","name":"Virtous Integration (Do not enable)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"salesforce","name":"Salesforce"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"boca","name":"BOCA Printer"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["password"],"id":"passwordField","name":"Password Field (Not ready at all)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"oauth2","name":"OAUTH2 Form Authentication"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"saml","name":"SAML Form Authentication"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customWizard","name":"Custom Wizard For Crossfit (do not enable)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"capacityDisplay","name":"Capacity Display for Campaign Listing"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"regOptionsDisplay","name":"Display RegOptions in Datatables"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"fieldPassword","name":"Password protected fields"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["vanityNumber"],"id":"bibs","name":"Bib Management"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customReports","name":"Custom Reports"},{"fields":[],"id":"extendedDisabledFields","name":"Extended Fields that can be disabled"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"ccb","name":"CCB"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"f1","name":"Fellowship 1"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"boxoffice","name":"Box Office App"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"reservedSeating","name":"Reserved Seating"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"kindful","name":"Kindful Integration"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"hardstockTickets","name":"Hardstock Tickets"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"webhook-sms","name":"SMS Webhook"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"transfers","name":"Transfers"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["trackside"],"id":"motocross","name":"Motocross"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"ticketShortcodes","name":"Ticket Shortcodes"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["instagram"],"id":"instagram","name":"Instagram Widget"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"checkinSettings","name":"Checkin 2 Settings"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"tsys","name":"TSYS Gateway"},{"enabled":true,"fields":["purchaseProtection"],"id":"purchaseProtection","name":"Purchase Protection"}],"gf_plan_chosen":true,"pricing":{"global":{"registrantFree":0,"ticketFree":0,"orderFree":0},"products":{"giving.com":{"recurring":59},"reg.com":{"registrantFree":0},"red.com":{},"ticket.com":{"ticketFree":0,"boxOfficeTicketFree":0,"orderFree":0}}},"timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","upgrades":{"account":[{"id":5,"name":"Custom Gateway"}],"giving.com":[],"red.com":[],"reg.com":[],"ticket.com":[]}}'
3, b'{"address":"123 Fischer Ave.","city":"Costa Mesa","country":"USA","customerPortal":{"contact":{"email":"email@rockharbor.org","phone":"7143123454"},"design":{"accentColor":"#38485A","fontColor":"#ffffff"},"settings":{"unsubscribeVisible":true},"welcomeEmail":{"buttonText":"Access your account","fromName":"Rockharbor Church","message":"Hello,\\n\\nThis is a friendly notice to let you know your account is confirmed and setup for donations to Rockharbor Church.  Visit and bookmark the link below to easily access your account in the future.\\n\\nGod Bless,\\nRockharbor Church"}},"features":[{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"achInvoices","name":"ACH Invoices"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["vanityNumber"],"id":"bibs","name":"Bib Management"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"boca","name":"BOCA Printer"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"capacityDisplay","name":"Capacity Display for Campaign Listing"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"ccb","name":"CCB"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customReports","name":"Custom Reports"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"customWizard","name":"Custom Wizard For Crossfit (do not enable)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"regOptionsDisplay","name":"Display RegOptions in Datatables"},{"fields":[],"id":"extendedDisabledFields","name":"Extended Fields that can be disabled"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"f1","name":"Fellowship 1"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"hardstockTickets","name":"Hardstock Tickets"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"hostedEvents","name":"Hosted Events (Virtual Event)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"virtualRace","name":"Virtual Race"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["instagram"],"id":"instagram","name":"Instagram Widget"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"kindful","name":"Kindful Integration"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"massCancellation","name":"Mass Cancellation"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["memberManager"],"id":"memberManager","name":"Member Manager"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["trackside"],"id":"motocross","name":"Motocross"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["dynamicOptions"],"id":"dynamicOptions","name":"Dynamic Options"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"inventoryMultiDay","name":"Multi-Day Sub Inventory (Does not work w/ Timeslots)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"pageTemplates","name":"Page Templates"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["password"],"id":"passwordField","name":"Password Field (Not ready at all)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"fieldPassword","name":"Password protected fields"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"pineapple","name":"Pineapple Gateway"},{"enabled":true,"fields":["purchaseProtection"],"id":"purchaseProtection","name":"Purchase Protection"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"saml","name":"SAML Form Authentication"},{"enabled":false,"id":"seasonPass","name":"Season Pass"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"webhook-sms","name":"SMS Webhook"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"ticketShortcodes","name":"Ticket Shortcodes"},{"fields":[],"id":"transfers","name":"Transfers"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["trio"],"id":"trio","name":"Trio Rewards Verification"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"tsys","name":"TSYS Gateway"},{"enabled":false,"fields":["virtuous"],"id":"virtuous","name":"Virtous Integration (Do not enable)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"virtualPro","name":"Virtual Events Pro"},{"enabled":true,"fields":[],"id":"nmi","name":"NMI Gateway"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"cybersourcerest","name":"Cybersource REST"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"webhook-backend","name":"Webhooks: (Backend: Edit / Cancel)"},{"enabled":false,"fields":[],"id":"billingCountryLockdown","name":"Billing Country Lockdown"}],"gf_plan_chosen":true,"metatags":{"giving.com":[],"red.com":[],"reg.com":[],"ticket.com":[]},"pricing":{"global":{"customVolume":0,"registrantFree":0,"ticketFree":0,"orderFree":0},"products":{"giving.com":{"monthly":0,"customVolume":0,"email":0,"sms":0},"red.com":{},"reg.com":{"registrantFree":0},"ticket.com":{"ticketFree":0,"orderFree":0,"boxofficeTicketFree":0}}},"state":"CA","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","upgrades":{"account":[{"id":3,"name":"Communication Center"},{"id":5,"name":"Custom Gateway"},{"id":4,"name":"Webhooks"}],"giving.com":[{"id":1,"name":"Donor Permissions"},{"id":2,"name":"Text2Give"}],"red.com":[],"reg.com":[],"ticket.com":[]},"zip":"12345"}'
4, b'{"pricing":{"global":{},"products":{"giving.com":{"customVolume":0}}}}'
```

Comment: Is there any error details in `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` or `STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL ` sys tables?

Comment: @dfundako i'm not sure how to get to those as the script is running in a docker container in ecs

Comment: Can you post a sample from the S3 file that you are trying to load?  Exact syntax and quoting is important to how to configure the COPY command.

Comment: The issue seems to be with thr `b'` you might need decode the data or remove them from the csv file

Comment: @DataWrangler that was it!!! Thank you so much :) Please make a post so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with thr `b'` you might need decode the data or remove them from the csv file.

Once the file has been corrected the commands as listed by you previously should work like charm.